# Setting variable and counting

Tags: php

```
$counter = "";
if($sWall>1){
    $counter = $counter + $sWall;
}
if($sWC>1){
    $counter = $counter + $sWC;
}
if($sOther>1){
    $counter = $counter + $sOther;
}
if(!(empty($counter))){
    echo "(".$counter.") ";
}
```

This is what I have that does not work.
`$sOther`, `$sWC`, `$sWall` is `mysql_num_rows`.  I wish to echo out e.g (3) if you have 1 in `$sOther`, 1 in `$sWC` and 1 in `$sWall`.

How can I do that, what I did is just something I tried.

Comment: How does it  "not work"?  Error?  (If so, please edit it into the question)  Unexpected output?  (If so, please tell us what that is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$counter = $sWall + $sWC + $sOther;
if ($counter) {
    echo '(' . $counter . ')';
}
```

That's it ;) Remember: Short code is good code.

Answer (score 3):

Counter is a string type. First line should be `$counter = 0;`.
And you should change `if ($sWall>1)` to `if ($sWall>0)` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

In the code above, $counter will not increment if any of the checked values are equal to 1. You should use if($sWall**>=**1). It might be even easier to simply add `$sWall + $sWC + $sOther`

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;
if($sWall>0){
    $counter = $counter + $sWall;
}
if($sWC>0){
    $counter = $counter + $sWC;
}
if($sOther>0){
    $counter = $counter + $sOther;
}
if($counter>0){
    echo "(".$counter.") ";
}
```

Use an int if you want to store numbers, so you can just check if it's greater than zero and echo it.

Note that you could also write `$counter += $sWall;` instead of `$counter = $counter + $sWall;`, so you don't have to type that much.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize numeric values to `0`. This isn't the source of your problem, as PHP will convert the empty string to `0` for you when you use numeric operators like `+`, but symantically it's better to state up front that `$counter` is numeric.

Once you've added your values, test if `$counter` is greater than 0 rather than using `empty`.  You can use shorthand `+=` operators and simply test `$counter` to make the whole method a little more succinct.

Finally, you've chosen the wrong comparison operator (`>`) to test your values. If you want to include `1`, use `>=`:

```
$counter = 0;
if($sWall  >= 1) $counter += $sWall;
if($sWC    >= 1) $counter += $sWC;
if($sOther >= 1) $counter += $sOther;

if ($counter)
    echo "($counter)";
```